# How to escape input in PHP?

Tags: php, file, escaping

I have a PHP page that accepts input from a form post, but instead of directing that input to a database it is being used to retrieve a file from the file system. What is a good method for escaping a string destined for the file system rather then a database? Is mysql_real_escape_string() appropriate?

Comment: AFAIK, as long as you're only looking for files (not running commands using `exec()`, etc), you're fine using raw input.

Comment: Make sure someone cannot submit a path like `../../../something` or `/dev/null` and access the "wrong area" and you should be fine.

Comment: This is being used to include the file in the output.

Comment: In the use case you describe (allowing a user to select a file from the filesystem), the best way is to not directly apply the user input to the file system. Instead, have the form return some sort of identifier that is instead used to retrieve a file (eg, file_id of 1 retrtieves foo.txt). To escape the string as you describe, the bare minimum would be to make sure you're going into a particular sub-directory and remove `..`s and/or use the `basename()` of the user input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using user-provided input to specify a filename directory, you'll have to make sure that the provided filename/path isn't trying to break "out" of your site's playground.

e.g. having something like

```
readfile($_GET['filepath']);
```

will send out ANYTHING on your server that the attack knows the path for. Even something like

```
readfile('/path/to/your/site/download/' . $_GET['filepath']);
```

accomplishes the same, if the user specifies enough '../../../' to get to whatever file they want.

mysql_real_escape_string() is **NOT** appropriate for this, as you're not doing a database operation. Use appropriate tools for appropriate jobs. In a goofy way, m_r_e_s() is a banana, and you need a giraffe. Something like

```
readfile('/path/to/your/site/download/' . basename($_GET['filepath']));
```

would be relatively save as basename() will extract only the filename portion of the user-provided file, so even if they pass in `../../../../../etc/passwd`, basename will return only `passwd`.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is to `basename` as `banana` is to `giraffe`. I think I remember that from the SAT analogies. :)

Answer (score 0):

You always only need to escape characters that are otherwise interpreted by your target system. For databases you usually make sure to escape quotes so you use `mysql_real_escape_string` or others. If your target is html, you usually use `htmlspecialchars` to make sure you get rid of html special characters (namely `<`, `>` and `&`). If your target is CSV, you basically only need to make sure line breaks and the CSV separator are escaped.

So depending on your target you can either reuse an existing escape function, define your own, or even go without one. If all you do is dump the input in a single file, then there is not much you need to take care of, as long as *you* specify the filename and that file is never used (or interpreted) by anything else than your application.

So think of what kind of special characters your target format requires for it to work, and simply escape those. You can usually ignore the rest.

#### edit:

If you want to use the input as the file path or file name, you can simply decide yourself how gracious you are, and what characters you want to support. A simple method would be to replace *everything* except latin characters and numbers (and maybe some special characters like `_` and `-`) by something else. For example:

```
preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', '_', $text );
```